# only users with daily activity SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Data is something like this

```
Installed(Days ago)   Activity    UserID   withdraw
52                    11/4/16     111      null
40                    15/4/16     112      5
15                    26/4/16     113      null
16                    17/4/16     117      null
17                    14/4/16     135      2
```

I need to make a list of users who had activity 7 days in a row after installation date (including), except for users who withdrew.

Comment: Please provide more details like result what you are expecting.

Comment: @SandeepKumar just a list of UserID like ['123','145'.'112']. did I understand you correctly?

Comment: In the above quertion there is no user id like 123 , 145, 122 .. Please Update your question with more sample data and result expected from that data.

Comment: I dont know how people usually put in data here, I'm doing it by hand, so I only supplied an example. for me to do it 7 times for a few people would take a while.

Comment: From the above data what are you expecting result? Which user id will come?

Comment: Where is the installation date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've had to make some assumptions here. I've assumed that the table your using will store a row for each day the user has logged in. Something like this;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (InstalledDaysAgo int, Activity datetime, UserID int, Withdraw int)
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
 ('10','05-01-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-02-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-03-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-04-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-05-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-06-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-07-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-08-2016','111',NULL)
,('10','05-01-2016','112',NULL)
,('10','05-03-2016','112',NULL)
,('10','05-07-2016','112',NULL)
,('10','05-08-2016','112',NULL)
,('10','05-01-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-02-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-03-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-04-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-05-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-06-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-07-2016','113',5)
,('10','05-08-2016','113',5)
```

I've then assumed that you just want a list of all users, how long ago the installation was and whether they logged on for all 7 days after installation;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.InstalledDaysAgo
,a.UserID
,CASE WHEN fw.FirstWeekLogins = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END All7Days
FROM #TestData a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    UserID
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Activity BETWEEN CAST((cast(GETDATE() as date)) AS datetime) -InstalledDaysAgo AND CAST((cast(GETDATE() as date)) AS datetime) -(InstalledDaysAgo-6) 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
         END) FirstWeekLogins
    FROM #TestData
    GROUP BY UserID
) fw
ON a.UserID = fw.UserID

WHERE Withdraw IS NULL
```

This won't account for anything with the InstalledDaysAgo field that's less than 7 but should be a starting point for you.

Your data will look something like this;

```
InstalledDaysAgo    UserID  All7Days
10                  111     1
10                  112     0
```

(Don't forget this bit)

```
DROP TABLE #TestData
```

Comment: Your assumptions were correct. thanks and sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: Sure, no worries. It's worth taking that extra time when asking a question and include as much information as you can. It'll help you get a much more relevant response quickly.